# Blogengine.NET on mono

Tags: programming, mono, monodevelop

I'd like to set up the new 2.7 Blogengine on Mono using Ubuntu, but I experience issues with it.

It has support for mono because there is another project called Blogengine.Web on Codeplex which is created for such as MonoDevelop. I've got the source using TortuiseHG and tried to compile on a clean Ubuntu 12.04 using the Monodevelop.

The source compiled successfully, but when I tried to run it, I get the following exception:

---

```
Compilation Error

Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.

Compiler Error Message: CS0436: The type `Resources.labels' conflicts with the imported type of same name'. Ignoring the imported type definition

Source Error:

Line 26:         public static System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
Line 27:             get {
Line 28:                 if ((labels._resourceManager != null)) {
Line 29:                     return labels._resourceManager;
Line 30:                 }


Source File: /tmp/jeremy-temp-aspnet-0/5593eb70/App_Web_10b27ebd_0.cs  Line: 28

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

dmcs /target:library /lib:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin" /debug+ /optimize- /warnaserror /warn:4 /out:"/tmp/jeremy-temp-aspnet-0/5593eb70/App_GlobalResources.70277c2e.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.CSharp/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Services/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.Services.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.EnterpriseServices/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.IdentityModel/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.IdentityModel.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Runtime.Serialization/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xaml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xaml.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceModel/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ServiceModel.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceModel.Web/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Extensions/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.Extensions.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml.Linq/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.DynamicData/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Data.Linq/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.Linq.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.ApplicationServices/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /r:"/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Management/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/System.Web.Razor.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/System.Web.WebPages.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/System.Web.Helpers.dll" /r:"/tmp/jeremy-temp-aspnet-0/5593eb70/App_GlobalResources.6d61537.dll" /r:"/tmp/jeremy-temp-aspnet-0/5593eb70/App_Code.3e3211f7.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/AjaxMin.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/BlogEngine.Core.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/BlogEngine.Web.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/BlogML.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/NuGet.Core.dll" /r:"/home/jeremy/Development/Blogengine.Web/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Web/bin/System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /d:DEBUG /resource:"/tmp/jeremy-temp-aspnet-0/5593eb70/Resources.labels.resources"  -- "/tmp/jeremy-temp-aspnet-0/5593eb70/App_Web_10b27ebd_0.cs" 

/tmp/jeremy-temp-aspnet-0/5593eb70/App_Web_10b27ebd_0.cs(28,22): error CS0436: The type `Resources.labels' conflicts with the imported type of same name'. Ignoring the imported type definition
/tmp/jeremy-temp-aspnet-0/5593eb70/App_GlobalResources.6d61537.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
```

---

Sorry for the question, but I did not get answers on the Blogengine forum, so I decided to ask the pros ;-)

Thanks in advance,
KU